# Use of Zorn's Lemma in showing nilradical equals intersection of primes

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm very confused as to the use of Zorn's lemma in showing that the nilradical of a ring is the intersection of all the prime ideals.

Namely, we let $a \notin N$, where $N$ is the nilradical. Then we let $\Sigma$ be the set of ideals of our ring $A$ such that $a^n \notin \Sigma$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. $\Sigma$ is non-empty as the zero ideal is in it.

Next, we order $\Sigma$ by inclusion, and in any chain we just take the union of all the ideals, which due to the inclusion is just the sum of the ideals in the chain. We then conclude that this ideal is an upper-bound of the chain, and apply Zorn's lemma to get that there is a maximal element in $\Sigma$.

First, for the sake of my sanity, the upper bound we got in this case also happens to be a maximal element, yes? It's an ideal in $\Sigma$ that dominates every other element in the chain by inclusion.

My main question is this: Can't this be done for any ring and for any set $\Sigma$ of ideals in the ring? We just order $\Sigma$ by inclusion and conclude that there's a maximal element by using the union in any chain as an upper bound. But then doesn't this imply every ring is Noetherian (which is obviously false)?

Thanks,

Garnet

Comment: The upper bound that you get is not necessarily a maximal element. It will dominate every element of the chain, but there can still be other elements of $\Sigma$ that dominate it -- the chain that you're considering certainly need not contain all of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Oh! Okay, right! Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: In response to your main question: indeed that can be done for any set of ideals $\Sigma$ with the property that the union of any chain will be in $\Sigma$, but not for any arbitrary set of ideals (which would be required for the ring to be Noetherian).

Comment: Thanks whosleon. Do you mean taking the union takes us outside the set of ideals we're considering? Can you give an explicit example of this?

Comment: @Garnet Yes that is what I mean. Taking any non-Noetherian ring and any ascending, non-terminating chain of ideals in it, e.g. the ring of polynomials in infinitely many variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$, let $\Sigma$ be the set of ideals $(X_1)\subseteq (X_1, X_2)\subseteq (X_1, X_2, X_3)\subseteq \ldots$. Then the union of that entire chain is the ideal $(X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots)$ (all polynomials with 0 constant term) is not in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Ah, all right! I had thought of that example, but failed to consider that the set of ideals only contains ones that are finitely generated, whereas the infinite union is not. Thanks!

Comment: @Garnet remember that an equivalent condition for a ring to be Noetherian is for all ideals in the ring to be finitely generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what happens when we do this for a chain of ideals in an arbitrary commutative ring.

Given $I_0 \subset I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \cdots$, we form $I=\bigcup I_j$.  This is an ideal, and an upper bound for the chain.  But it need not *belong* to the chain, which is a requirement for verifying the noetherian condition.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't belong to the set of ideals we're considering? It can be outside the chain while still belonging to our set of ideals, at which point Zorn's Lemma should give us an upper bound.

Can you give an explicit example of where taking the union takes us outside the set of ideals?

Comment: @Garnet Ah, I think I see what definitions you're using.  Sure: let $\Sigma$ be the collection of all finitely generated ideals.  Then, if we are working in a ring that has non-finitely generated ideals, there will be chains that cause this problem.

Comment: @Garnet For example, let $R = \mathbb{C}[X_1, X_2,\ldots]$.  Then, consider the chain of finitely generated ideals $(X_1)\subset(X_1,X_2)\subset(X_1,X_2,X_3)\subset\cdots$.  The union takes us outside of the collection of finitely generated ideals.